# Send email with multiple messages to different users in sendgrid

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

We are using sendgrid for email,

we have tried,

```
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$emails = array("foo@bar.com", "another@another.com", "other@other.com");
$email->setTos($emails);
$email->setHtml(array($message1,$message1));
$sendgrid->send($email);
```

How to set different - different `$email->setHtml(array($message1,$message1))` at a time.

Comment: explain `different - different $message at a time.`?

Comment: @urfusion, edited question

Comment: So you want to send different messages to different users? You should use different instances for that.

Comment: as I understand from your question you want to send different message to different email ids. So you can do that by create a loop of email ids and messages and call send function each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per I understand from your question you want to send different messages to different email ids. Which can be achieve by

```
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$emails = array("foo@bar.com", "another@another.com", "other@other.com");
$message = array("message1","message2","message3"); //create a array of messages according to email ids 
$i =0 ;
foreach ($emails as $value) {
    $email->setTos($value);
    $email->setHtml($message[$i]);
    $sendgrid->send($email);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: When `$i == 2`, this will fail on `$message`.

Comment: @AlejandroIván: I just create an example for understanding the approach.

Comment: @SagarPanchal : You are welcome. Glad to know it work.

Comment: @urfusion, in this first recipient getting all mails

Comment: @SagarPanchal : I just the code(only loop with email id) and work for me. output of the loop I am getting is `foo@bar.com
message1
another@another.com
message2
other@other.com
message3`. Let me try it with `sendgrid`

Answer (score 1):

As your question is confusing, I will assume you want to send different email messages to all users in the list. So:

```
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$emails = array("foo@bar.com", "another@another.com", "other@other.com");
$messages = array("message1", "message2");

foreach ($messages as $msg) { // Grab every message...
    $email->setTos($emails); // for everyone...
    $email->setHtml($msg); // set it as the body...
    $sendgrid->send($email); // and send it.
}
```